# Error durante la ejecución de Sonar-runner, Fail to download libraries from server

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu

Estoy intentando instalar **SonarQube Runner**, usando las siguientes versiones:

- sonarqube-5.1
- sonar-runner-dist-2.4
- mysql 5.1.63
- jdk 1.7.0_79
- ubuntu 11.4 de 32 bits

Ya he configurado:

```
sonar/conf/sonar.properties  
sonar-runner/conf/sonar-runner.properties
```

Y ya he creado el archivo de configuración dentro de mi proyecto a analizar:

```
sonar-project.properties
```

El *SonarQube* está corriendo correctamente, lo puedo corroborar haciendo:

```
service sonar status
```

Pero si corro:

```
sonar-runner -X
```

Me encuentro con el siguiente error:

```
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.7.0_79 Oracle Corporation (32-bit)
Linux 2.6.38-8-generic i386
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: Runner configuration file: /opt/sonar-runner/conf/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: /home/taller/taller2016/U3D_2016/sonar-project.properties
INFO: Default locale: "es_AR", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /home/taller/taller2016/U3D_2016/./.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.185s
Final Memory: 0M/53M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download libraries from server
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars.dowloadFiles(Jars.java:78)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars.download(Jars.java:57)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:46)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.checkVersionAndDownload(JarDownloader.java:37)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:71)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Status returned by url : 'http://localhost:9002/sonar/batch_bootstrap/index' is invalid : 404
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:94)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars.dowloadFiles(Jars.java:64)
    ... 12 more
```

¿Qué debo hacer o cambiar para solucionar este error?

El *access.log* de *SonarQube* genera:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/oct/2016:16:17:34 -0300] "GET /sonar/api/server/version HTTP/1.1" 200 3 "-" "SonarQubeRunner/2.4"  
127.0.0.1 - - [06/oct/2016:16:17:34 -0300] "GET /sonar/batch_bootstrap/index HTTP/1.1" 302 109 "-" "SonarQubeRunner/2.4"  
127.0.0.1 - - [06/oct/2016:16:17:34 -0300] "GET /sonar/api/maintenance HTTP/1.1" 404 1045 "-" "SonarQubeRunner/2.4"
```

Comment: Gracias ArtEze!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el servidor que deseaba instalar *SonarQube* tenía una versión de Java 6. Pero esta versión de *SonarQube* y de *Sonar-runner* necesitan Java 7. Con lo cual actualizando a Java 7 se soluciona este error. 
Luego de esto surgió otro error más, pero eliminando la base de datos y volviéndola a generar, salió andando todo bien, y se puede ejecutar correctamente el *sonar-runner*.